# How to customised useNativeControls in expo-av Video

Tags: react-native, expo

## I want to three icons, two for video playing speed control and another one for video resolution change. Is there any way to add this kind of buttons ??

Here is my player:

```js
            <Video
                key={videoId}
                ref={video}
                style={styles.videoPlayer}
                source={{
                  uri: videofiles?.link,
                }}
                rate={1.0}
                posterSource={{ uri: thumbnail }}
                usePoster={!isActivity}
                useNativeControls
                resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
                isLooping
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => {
                  statusChangeEvent(status);
                }}
                onFullscreenUpdate={onFullscreenUpdate}
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not modify your native controller. But you can use a hacky solution by using  **Pressable**. You have to wrap your video component with Pressable. And after that, you can show your customize modal.
Here is an Example:

```
<Pressable>
 <>
  <Video
    ...
    ...
  />
  //your customize modal
  ...
  ...
 </>
</Pressable>
```